# error while deploy app with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have developed an app and now am trying to deployed it on Tomcat. when I start `start.bat` file in Tomcat directory. My console doesn't display any errors and when I open log files, I see this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xmk.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
```

On many forums people say that I didn't add `jaxws-rt.jar` lib. But I have added it. First I added it as a dependency in maven. After that I deleted the dependency and downloaded the library from official site and added it to my lib folder. This too didn't help. So how can I fix this error?
**UPDATE**

full stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class 

    com.sun.xmk.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xmk.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Double check did you add it to the Tomcat library folder ?

Comment: Just as experiment: try to put the `jaxws-rt.jar` to tomcat/lib directory. Try to run tomcat without your application. Does it work? Please send full stack trace. It may be helpful

Comment: @AlexR look at update

Comment: and yes. without my app tomcat works fine

Comment: See recommendation of @Pradeep Pati. Let us know it it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the jars in your app's `WEB-INF/lib` dir, put it under the `lib` dir under Tomcat install directory. That should fix the error.